# Simple Impulse Response DSP Hardware

Tags: impulse-response, hardware-implementation

I developed some complex chains of filters and crossovers. After that I have created IRs from the entire chains. 
Applying these IRs in software works perfectly. 
Now I wonder what is the easiest (and reasonably cheap) way of implementing this on a dsp. All the dsp would have to do, is to perform the multiplications and additions resulting from applying the IR to the incoming signal.

Thanks!

Comment: Look for vendors' developer kits and their tools, and pick one. For example: https://www.ti.com/tools-software/hw-kits-boards.html

Comment: If you want to go the SHArC route instead of TI, i might recommend getting something from Danville Signal Processing.